# IOS BLE communication write value;

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am writing my first IOS App, to communicate with the Bluegiga BLE chip. I need to read and write values. The issue I am having is that, I am not able to write the value the first time I run the program. I do not get any error. It shows the last value which was written as the current value. When I re-run the program the correct value is updated correctly. Its delaying my project. Any suggestion will be of great help. I am using the following code snippet.

```
CBPeripheral        *servicePeripheral;
NSData              *readIndex;
CBCharacteristic    *readIdxCharacteristic;

[servicePeripheral writeValue:readIndex forCharacteristic:readIdxCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{

    if ([characteristic isEqual:readIdxCharacteristic] ){
        [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:readIdxCharacteristic];
        NSLog(@"Read Index Characteristic Written Check%@",characteristic.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing the value after you get the `didConnectPeripheral:` callback that says you are totally connected and good to go? You be be writing before it's ready.

Comment: Yes I am using didConnectPeripheral callback. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing the `characteristic.value` immediately after the call to `readValueForCharacteristic`, but it takes some time for Core-Bluetooth to contact the peripheral, request a value for the characteristic and for the peripheral to reply.

If you refer to the [documentation for this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011289-CH1-SW8) you will see -

> **Discussion**
>
> When you call this method to read the value of a
>   characteristic, the peripheral calls the
>   peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: method of its
>   delegate object. If the value of the characteristic is successfully
>   retrieved, you can access it through the characteristic’s value
>   property.

So, you need to access `characteristic.value` in your `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` `CBPeripheral` delegate method